# MIPS: Infinite loop with branches

Tags: mips, infinite-loop, mars-simulator

So I have a program that takes an input from the user (integer above 0) and adds up all even numbers below it to achieve a return answer (Ex: input: 7; ans: 2 + 4 + 6 = 12).

The issue with this program is that it's meant to break out of the loop based on if my 'active even variable' ($t1) > the input.  Although my program never seems to properly interpret the branch and loops indefinitely until $t1 overflows (I have checked the debugger and know that the program does run the branch line every time).  Below is my code:

```
    .data   
    
N:       .word 0
Result:  .word 0

    .text
    
    
    .globl main
initialize:
    li $v0, 5      #getting arg1 from user
    syscall
    la $t0, N
    sw $v0, 0($t0)
    
    li $t1, 2
    li $t2, 0
main:                    
    blt $t0, $t1, fin2
fori:
    add $t2, $t2, $t1 #t2 += t1
    add $t1, $t1, 2   #t1 += 2
    
    slt $t5, $t1, $t0
    bne $t5, $zero, fori
fin:
    
    
    li $v0,1              #prints return value
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

fin2:
    
    
    li $v0,1              #prints return value
    move $a0, $zero
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't know if you NEED to be using word storage and such, but really you were just over complicating it in doing so. All you needed was a simple loop which has a counter that increments by 2, checks if it is larger than the initial value, and then add that overall value to the result

```
.text    
.globl main

initialize: 
    li $v0, 5           # Getting arg1 from user
    syscall             # System call
    move $t0, $v0       # Store the input value in $t0
        
    li $t1, 0           # Initializing the result register
    li $t2, 0           # Initializing the addition/counter register
main:                    

loop:
    add $t2, $t2, 2     # Increase the value to be added by 2 (next even value)
    bge $t2, $t0, fin   # Check if the increment is larger than or equal to the initial input, if so break to finish
    add $t1, $t1, $t2   # Increment the result by adding the even value
    j loop              # jump bak to the top of the loop

fin:
    li $v0,1            # let the system know an integer is going to be printed
    move $a0, $t1       # Load the result into the $a0 register (the register that prints values)
    syscall             # System Call

    li  $v0, 10         # Let the system know the program is going to exit
    syscall             # System Call
```

So as you can see `$t2` increments by 2 each time. After each increment it is compared to the input value. If the input (`$t0`) than `$t2` then add the value of `$t2` to the result (`$t1`). This way there is an increment counter which is also used to add the necessary even value to the result.

---

Edit:

Not sure if this is entirely what you meant but I just tossed in some loads and saves, using the s registers as those are the register that are supposed to be used when saving values.

```
.data

N:      .word 0
Result: .word 0

.text    

.globl main

initialize:
    li $v0, 5           # Getting arg1 from user
    syscall             # System Call
    la $s0, N           # Load the address of N into $s0
    sw $v0, 0($s0)      # Store the input value in 0 index of N
                
    li $t2, 0           # Initializing the addition/counter register

    la $s1, Result      # Load the address of Result into $s1
main:                    
    sw $t2, 0($s1)      # Setting the 0 index of Result to 0
loop:
    add $t2, $t2, 2     # Increase the value to be added by 2 (next even value)
    lw  $t4, 0($s0)     # Loading the input value into the $t4 register
    bge $t2, $t4, fin   # Check if the increment is larger than or equal to the initial input, if so break to finish
    lw  $t4, 0($s1)     # Loading the current result into the $t4 register
    add $t4, $t4, $t2   # Increment the result by adding the even value
    sw $t4, 0($s1)      # Saving the new current result into the $t4 register
    j loop              # jump bak to the top of the loop

fin:
    li $v0,1            # let the system know an integer is going to be printed
    lw $a0, 0($s1)      # Load the result into the $a0 register (the register that prints values)
    syscall             # System Call

    li  $v0, 10         # Let the system know the program is going to exit
    syscall             # System Call
```

Comment: Thanks FivePly, that reworked loop seemed to do the trick.  In all frankness, I needed the vars as they were requirements to my program (to load/save to N and result), but your solution got rid of the infinite loop issue i was having.

Comment: @CalebErnst My pleasure :) but you were supposed to set N to the user input and the result to the final result or update it periodically?

Comment: No need to update it periodically, just get the final answer and store it in "Result", N would stay the same and be saved back around initialization.  But I was able to do that myself so all good.